# java Android Spanned Html.fromHtml(stringWithCDATA) still shows tags as text

Tags: java, android, cdata, spanned

Usually I use `<![CDATA[..here's text]]>` in my Resources Strings so when I do

```
Spanned sp=Html.fromHtml(getResources.getString(R.string.myString));
myTextView.setText(sp);
```

I get text with all the tags like  **, 
 etc working as they should.**

but now I build String during some metod like :

```
String result="<![CDATA[";
//some code
result+="<b>Chapter :"+chapterNumber+"</b><br /><br />"
//some other additions and in the end
result+="]]>";

Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(result);
myTextView.setText(sp);
```

and I see all my tags on the screen instead of them being implemented, like : Chapter :1
...

I tried to use StringBuilder instead, but result is the same.

What should I do for the tags to word right in my case?

Comment: you use Html.fromHtml, right? it doesnt support all html tags but still cdata has nothing to do with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do for the tags to word right in my case?

Get rid of the `CDATA`:

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml("<b>Chapter :"+chapterNumber+"</b><br /><br />");
myTextView.setText(sp);
```

Comment: hmm.. why did I need that CDATA in first place ?:)

Comment: @user2976267: In resources, you use the `CDATA` to prevent the XML parser for the XML resource files from messing with your tagged HTML. Here, you are just assembling HTML directly, so no `CDATA` is required.